# Aerospike %age of available write blocks is less when hard disk space is available

Tags: aerospike

We found ourselves this problem. Config is as follows :-

```
Aerospike version : 3.14
Underlying hard disk : non-SSD

Variable Name   Value
memory-size 5 GB
free-pct-memory 98 %
available_pct   4 %
max-void-time   0 millisec
stop-writes 0
stop-writes-pct 90 %
hwm-breached    true
default-ttl 604,800 sec
max-ttl 315,360,000 sec
enable-xdr  false
single-bin  false
data-in-memory  false
```

[image]

Can anybody please help us out with this ? What could be a potential reason for this ?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-percentage-of-available-writes-less-even-with-high-disk-space-availability/4815.

Answer (score 3):

Aerospike only writes to free blocks. A block may contain any number of records that fit. If your write/update pattern is such that a block never falls below 50% active records(the default threshold for defragmenting: `defrag-lwm-pct`), then you have a bunch of "empty" space that can't be utilized. Read more about defrag in the [managing storage](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/storage#aerospike-s-automatic-storage-reclamation-processes) page.

Recovering from this is much easier with a cluster that's not seeing any writes. You can **increase** defrag-lwm-pct, so that more blocks are eligible and gets defragmented.

Another cause could be just that the HDD isn't fast enough to keep up with defragmentation.

You can read more on possible resolutions in the [Aerospike KB - Recovering from Available Percent Zero](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/recovering-from-available-percent-zero/715). Don't read past "Stop service on a node..."

Answer (score 2):

You are basically not defragging your perisistence storage device (75GB per node).  From the snapshot you have posted, you have about a million records on 3 nodes with 21 million expired. So looks like you are writing records with very short ttl and the defrag is unable to keep up.

Can you post the output of few lines when you are in this state of:

```
$ grep defrag /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log
```

and

`$ grep thr_nsup /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log` ?

What is your write/update load ? My suspicion is that you are only creating short ttl records and reading, not updating.

Depending on what you are doing, increasing `defrag-lwm-pct` may actually make things worse for you. I would  also tweak `nsup-delete-sleep` from 100 microseconds default but it will depend on what your log greps above show.  So post those, and lets see.

(Edit: Also, from the fact that you are not seeing evictions even though you are above the 50% HWM on persistence storage means your nsup thread is taking a very long time to run. That again points to `nsup-delete-sleep` value needing tuning for your set up.)